# How to unfold the results of an Oracle query based on the value of a column

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I have a table on a Oracle DB with two columns. I would like to see every row repeated as many times as the number stored in the second column. The table looks like this:

```
col1 col2  
a    2  
b    3  
c    1
```

I want to write a query that returns this:

```
col1 col2
a    2  
a    2   
b    3    
b    3    
b    3    
c    1
```

So the value from col2 dictates the number of times a row is repeated. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/18761/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( col1, col2 ) AS
          SELECT 'a', 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'b', 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'c', 1 FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT col1,
       col2
FROM   test t,
       TABLE(
         CAST( 
           MULTISET(
             SELECT LEVEL
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= t.col2
           )
           AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/18761/3/0)**:

```
| COL1 | COL2 |
|------|------|
|    a |    2 |
|    a |    2 |
|    b |    3 |
|    b |    3 |
|    b |    3 |
|    c |    1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with src (col1, col2) as (
    SELECT 'a', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c', 1 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    src.*
FROM
    src
    JOIN (
        SELECT LEVEL val FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT MAX(col2) FROM src)
    ) gen ON gen.val <= src.COL2
ORDER BY
    src.col1
```

or in Oracle 12 is possible to use

```
with src (col1, col2) as (
    SELECT 'a', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c', 1 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    src.*
FROM
    src
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT NULL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= src.col2)
ORDER BY
    col1;
```

Comment: Your first query does not work if: the value in `col2` is greater than the number of rows in the `src` table; if there are gaps in the numbers; or if there are duplicate numbers. (In the first 2 cases it will return too few rows and in the third case can return too many rows)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative (I've added an extra column just to show that other columns can be present), assuming that col1 is unique:

```
with src (col1, col2, col3) as (
    SELECT 'a', 'b', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b', 'c', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c', 'd', 1 FROM DUAL
)
select col1, col2, col3
from   src
connect by level <= col3
           and prior col1 = col1
           and prior sys_guid() is not null;

COL1 COL2       COL3
---- ---- ----------
a    b             2
a    b             2
b    c             3
b    c             3
b    c             3
c    d             1
```

Comment: `PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL` will work 99.9999999% of the time - however there is a minscule chance that it will return the same value twice and then you could get `ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data` (and you will have a bad time trying to replicate the error). `PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL` does not suffer from this.

Answer (score 0):

If a is your table then you can also do :

```
select a1.col1 , a1.col2 
      from a a1
      join  (select level col2  from dual 
      connect by level < ( select max(col2) + 1 from a))   a2
      on a2.col2 between 1 and a1.col2
```