# Unfold results of an Oracle query based on value and add a column with incrementing number per unfolding

Tags: oracle, hierarchical, correlated

This is a sub-question of the following: [How to unfold the results of an Oracle query based on the value of a column](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/32522718/how-to-unfold-the-results-of-an-oracle-query-based-on-the-value-of-a-column)

Instead of simply unfolding I want to also add an ID column that increments and makes each row unique.

So this table:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2 |
| b | 3 |
| c | 1 |

Should return this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | 1 |
| a | 2 | 2 |
| b | 3 | 1 |
| b | 3 | 2 |
| b | 3 | 3 |
| c | 1 | 1 |

I want to work of the correlated hierarchical query answer by MT0:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM   test t,
       TABLE(
         CAST( 
           MULTISET(
             SELECT LEVEL
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= t.col2
           )
           AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic self join should suffice here:

```sql
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col2 AS col3
FROM test t1
INNER JOIN test t2
    ON t1.col2 >= t2.col2;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo